# Wpf Application error for calculating how old I was in the year 2000

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application for homework which calculates how old I was in the year 2000.

It is not recognizing value in clickButton for some reason. This is what I have tried:

CS

```
namespace BirthdayApp
{
   public partial class MainWindow: Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         int curDate = 2020;
         InitializeComponent();
         message1.Text = "The year is " + curDate;
      }

      private void clickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         int curDate = 2020;
         message2.Text = ("You were ") + (value - curDate) + " in the year 2000";
      }
   }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
     <TextBox x:Name="value"/>
     <Label x:Name="label"/>
     <Button x:Name="button"/>
     <TextBlock x:Name="message2"/>
     <TextBlock x:Name="message1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Show the xaml for where you are entering the text

Comment: I just edited the body

Comment: how about if you try (Int32.Parse(value) - curDate) ? Looks like you have a string.  if you hover your mouse over the red squiggle line, what is the error message?

Comment: just tried that, it told me that I cannot convert a textbox to a string.

Comment: ahh do value.Text

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you all so much, this is my first time on stack overflow (hence why I had to show the pictures.

Comment: Glad I could help, when posting a question you should always post the error you get, also what you have tried. I can write up an answer for you. Glad to have you on Stack overflow and best of luck!

Comment: Please don't post code as images

Comment: I seem to not know how to post it as is, any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that in `clickButton` you are referencing the name of the `TextBox` by specifying value.  You want to access the `text` from that `TextBox`. You can do so by:

```
message2.Text = ("You were ") + (value.Text - curDate) + " in the year 2000";
```